# NumPy, .reshape()

Tags: python, numpy

What does this code do?

```
climate_results = np.concatenate((climate_data, yields.reshape(1000, 1)), axis=1)
```

Note : I have a variable called climate_data and yields

Comment: can please add the climate_data and yields variables to your code? concatenate is a method that concatenate two Arrays

Comment: Does this help? [numpy.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html),[numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.concatenate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), concatenate two arrays.

*(in your code you have 1000 row for climate_data and in this example I have 2 row for climate_data and we should reshape to 1000 or 2 row that can concatenate two array)*
see this example:

```
climate_data = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
# array([[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]])

yields = np.array([0,1])
# array([0, 1])

yields = np.array([0,1]).reshape(2,1)
# array([[0],
#        [1]])

climate_results = np.concatenate((climate_data, yields.reshape(2, 1)), axis=1)
climate_results
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

You can concatenate in `axis=0` like below:

```
climate_data = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
yields = np.array([[0,1]])
# array([[0, 1]])
climate_results = np.concatenate((climate_data, yields), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [0, 1]])
```